# Enabling 8dot3name functionality on massive external drive

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2019

We've just switched to a new file server, but a lot of our designers are having issues with file names which are too long. We have enabled `LongPathsEnabled` but the issues remain specifically for Adobe Creative Suite apps.

On comparison, the old server has 8.3 naming enabled which shortens the path such that Adobe apps can open and print the files with no issues.

I want to enable 8.3 naming on the new server, but the difference here is that it's an external direct-attached storage device whereas the old server used built-in disks. The volume is massive, about 70TB decompressed, but it is deduplicated to about 25TB.

Am I ok to simply enable 8.3 with the command below? Is there going to be an impact on performance and/or disk space, since as I understand it the 8.3 names are stored on the disk? Any other caveats that I might need to take into consideration?

```
fsutil 8dot3name set 0 Volume{25f8f92c-93fc-478e-a474-635502267fac}
```

Additionally, if the direct-attached storage were to be moved to a new server, would this setting be retained for the volume, or would it have to be set again on the new server?

EDIT

After a bit of research it seems that the setting only applies for newly created files. So in addition to the above, is there a way to force 8.3 name creation on all existing files?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is simply that file paths are too long, there are probably better and simpler solutions than forcing 8dot3 file name limits.

Are your designers accessing the files over the network? If so, create a file share for them to use on that specific path so they can access it directly at \server\sharedfolder, potentially eliminating a lot of characters in the path.

You can also create a junction point anywhere in the root or a high level folder. A junction point creates a link to the target folder, but looks and acts exactly like a new folder. When you open the folder in Windows Explorer, it behaves as if you opened the target folder. The basic syntax is:

```
junction <New Junction Directory Name> <Target Directory Path>
junction D:\ShortName "D:\Folder\Subfolder\Subfolder\Subfolder\Subfolder"
```

On a final note: are you Adobe CS apps updated to current or recent versions? This could affect compatibility with long paths as well.

Comment: Yes it's network, everyone accesses a single DFS namespace, and at most we could probably eliminate about 10 characters from the file path, which only resolves a handful of issues for us really. It would be difficult to implement junction points just because of the sheer number of files/folders. And yes fully up to date - I think it's just one of the implementations of MAX_PATH that aren't overriden by setting LongPathsEnabled.